# Common LISP Code explanation

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Can someone explain to me what this code does and how it works ?

```
(defun f (&optional (x nil) (y (if (atom x) nil (car x))))
 (cond ((atom x) y)
       ((< (car x) y) (f (cdr x) y))
       (t (f (cdr x) (car x)))))
```

Comment: if you don't understand the language, you should read about it, learn it's grammar. this is not the place for this kind of questions

Comment: What did you understand in the code ?

Comment: You can use the [`STEP`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_step.htm) or [`TRACE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_tracec.htm) to see how a function works.

Comment: Another good way to understand how code works is to write down the variables on a piece of paper, and pretend you're the computer executing the code.

Comment: It's not the simplest way to do it. Is this homework?

Comment: It's recursively looking for the largest element of `x` that's larger than `y`.  `x` and `y` are optional.  I"m a Scheme beginner, but could more of less read the code, and tested my conclusion by running the scheme equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick run through the code shows it's a function which returns the largest number given two numbers or a list of numbers. It'll return nil if given an atom and an error if one of the elements of the list is not a number.
here are some of the results I got:

`CL-USER> (f '(1 2 3 4))
4
CL-USER> (f '(1 5 2 4))
5
CL-USER> (f '(1 5 2 4 7))
7
CL-USER> (f 'y)
NIL
CL-USER> (f 3 'y)
Y`

A type error comes up when there is a non-numeric in the list:

`CL-USER> (f '(1 x 2 4 7))`

gives the following error
**The value
    X
is not of type
    NUMBER
when binding SB-KERNEL::X
    [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]**

As for how it works? The function compares numbers in a list, the first parameter, and a number, second param and returns the largest of them all. It does this by recursively comparing the first two numbers of the list returning the larger number which it compares to the rest of the list.